# Using powershell, unable to import ADDSDeployment module if installing Server-Media-Foundation feature

Tags: powershell

I am trying to setup AD + Exchange 2013 on win2k12 server, as part of the setup am executing below commands that run fine if I dont include Server-Media-Foundation, but fails if I do include. Error that I get is not making sense to me as its not complaining about SMF. I can get around by doing it in multiple steps, however, I would like to understand what mistake I am making here by trying to install all together.

Below code is being executed as part of user-data added to a win2k12 aws ec2 instance. 
I have tried executing directly as a ps1 file on a win2k12 server as well, with same results.

```
...
Install-WindowsFeature -Name AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools
Import-Module ADDSDeployment
$secpass=ConvertTo-SecureString <password string> -AsPlainText -Force
$dmnname = "company-01.local"
$dmnnetbios = "CMP-01"
Install-ADDSForest -CreateDnsDelegation:$false -DatabasePath "C:\Windows\NTDS" -DomainMode "Win2012R2" -DomainName $dmnname -DomainNetbiosName $dmnnetbios -ForestMode "Win2012R2" -InstallDns:$true -LogPath "C:\Windows\NTDS" -NoRebootOnCompletion:$false -SysvolPath "C:\Windows\SYSVOL" -SafeModeAdministratorPassword $secpass -Force:$true
...
```

Above runs successfully, server restarts at the end of this and when back online, I can see the AD Forest installed.

```
...
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Server-Media-Foundation
Install-WindowsFeature -Name AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools
Import-Module ADDSDeployment
$secpass=ConvertTo-SecureString <password string> -AsPlainText -Force
$dmnname = "company-01.local"
$dmnnetbios = "CMP-01"
Install-ADDSForest -CreateDnsDelegation:$false -DatabasePath "C:\Windows\NTDS" -DomainMode "Win2012R2" -DomainName $dmnname -DomainNetbiosName $dmnnetbios -ForestMode "Win2012R2" -InstallDns:$true -LogPath "C:\Windows\NTDS" -NoRebootOnCompletion:$false -SysvolPath "C:\Windows\SYSVOL" -SafeModeAdministratorPassword $secpass -Force:$true
...
```

Above run fails with error complaining about ADDSDeployment module, even though it had worked when not including Server-media-foundation feature install.

```
Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
True    Yes            SuccessRest... {Media Foundation}
WARNING: You must restart this server to finish the installation process.
WARNING: Windows automatic updating is not enabled. To ensure that your newly-installed role or feature is
automatically updated, turn on Windows Update.
True    Yes            SuccessRest... {Active Directory Domain Services, Group P...
WARNING: You must restart this server to finish the installation process.
WARNING: Windows automatic updating is not enabled. To ensure that your newly-installed role or feature is
automatically updated, turn on Windows Update.
Import-Module : The specified module 'ADDSDeployment' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At C:\run.ps1:8 char:1
+ Import-Module ADDSDeployment
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (ADDSDeployment:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Install-ADDSForest : The term 'Install-ADDSForest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At C:\run.ps1:12 char:1
+ Install-ADDSForest -CreateDnsDelegation:$false -DatabasePath "C:\Windows\NTDS" - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-ADDSForest:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
True    Yes            SuccessRest... {Active Directory Domain Services, Group P...
WARNING: You must restart this server to finish the installation process.
```

This seems to require a reboot; maybe that's what missing for the following Import-Module to work?
Although it's strange that it works in the first case, if you're really on the same OS.

I just went through this on a Win2019 which doesn't seem to require a reboot:

```
Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
True    No             Success        {Active Directory Domain Services, Group P...
```

Comment: Thats right. a Restart-COmputer was needed in between. I was using this code within the userdata section of AWS EC2 so was trying to avoid restart command. With some digging however was able to find suggestions online on how to use Windows Scheduled Tasks to schedule a 2nd script to run after restarting - this 2nd script contain the subsequent steps.